# Issue with full height image header on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently working on a website which features a full view height image header on all screen sizes. All was well until we encountered a problem with mobile devices where the size of the image would change on scroll, when the URL bar disappears. I was able to resolve this issue by writing a jQuery script that would set the height on load and orientation change, rather than using CSS rules. This worked very well, however I have encountered some new issues. The first is that on Safari, mobile landscape orientation only, the image header extends beyond the height of the screen. The second is that in iOS Chrome app, a black space appears under the image when scrolling up as well as the soft scroll arrow changes position. I would like to know if someone can provide any insight as to why this is happening in these scenarios only, or if there is are possible solutions out there.

```js
if (($(window).width() <= 1024 && $(window).width() >= 735) || ($(window).width() <= 414)) {
    var bg = $(".intro, .intro-inner, .intro-body, .intro-bg-item-image, .intro-bg-item, .intro-bg, .caroufredsel_wrapper");
    function resizeBackground() {
        bg.height( $(window).height());
    }
    $(window).load(resizeBackground);
    resizeBackground();
    
    $(window).on("orientationchange",function(event) {
        resizeBackground();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro-inner">
    <div class="intro-bg">
      <div class="intro-bg-item">
        <div class="intro-bg-item-image" style="background-image: url(css/images/pb/home-banner.jpg)"></div>
        <!-- /.intro-bg-item-image -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.intro-bg-item -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.intro-bg -->
  </div>
</div>
```

[LINK TO PAGE](https://gohrvst.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a viewport meta tag set?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I have '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">'